# Convert matrix with a string inside to a list. Python

Tags: python, list, matrix, type-conversion

Given a matrix with string and empty cells inside (name)
`print(name)`

```
[]
['Puchkin A.']
[]
['Kudryashova V.']
[]
```

How to convert this matrix into a list, approximately:

`[[], ['Puchkin A.'], [], ['Kudryashova V.'], []]`

Comment: Your input does not look like valid. Please double check.  Is something like this:  `inputs = "[] ['Puchkin A.'] ['Kudryashova V.'], [] "   Or ?

Comment: So you dont want the middle list from the string? E.g. `[[], ['Puchkin A.'], [], ['Kudryashova V.'], []]`

Comment: @user56700 Oh, I'm sorry. I missed it

Comment: @DanielHao Sorry. I missed []

Comment: @Mr.Dandomi Please add the exact input you have so we can give you a correct answer, if it's not a string, then what is it? Please provide an example.

Comment: @user56700 https://pastebin.com/dZyhLm7Y
Look at the 68th line

Comment: @Mr.Dandomi so it's an excel file?

Comment: @user56700 The program reads an excel file and reads a regular expression and writes it to the name variable in the form of a strange matrix with text inside

Comment: What is the output when you `print(name)` at line 70?

Comment: @user56700
https://ibb.co/8gm8YQ4

Comment: @Mr.Dandomi at line 62 insert `matrix = []` then line 69 `matrix.append(name)` print matrix after the loop `for obj in list_object:`

Comment: @user56700 https://pastebin.com/iWp6MGQX Error:     raise ValueError("matrix must be 2-dimensional")
ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional

Answer (score 1):

You could use `numpy`'s built in function [`matrix()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) and then use [`tolist()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = [[],
['Puchkin A.'],
[],
['Kudryashova V.'],
[]]
print((np.matrix(matrix)).tolist())
```

Comment: pastebin.com/dZyhLm7Y Look at the 68th line
A regular expression creates a matrix with string inside

Comment: raise ValueError("matrix must be 2-dimensional")
ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional

https://pastebin.com/iWp6MGQX